# Rails Bundle Install Error Makefile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

Hi!

Getting undreway with a new rails app, and get this error on a bundle install... I've installed both ruby and the ruby devkit

```
 C:/Ruby22/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20160630-12920-wctwey.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR=" clean
'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

make "DESTDIR="
'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

help? thanks, let me know what other info i can provide

Answer (score 0):

Did you initialize the Ruby DevKit? See https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit

You'll need to:

```
ruby dk.rb init
ruby dk.rb install
```